# Why Authorization header gets removed in iOS PATCH requests?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, alamofire

there. I got a very strange problem. The thing is that when i'm trying to send PATCH requests server says that no Authorization header contains token. The same for PUT request.Tried to sniff and found out that no Authorization header is sent at all. While any other types of request contain Authorization header. First thought its Alamofire framework specific problem, but using NSURLConnection requests and NSURLSession tasks gave me the same: NO AUTHORIZATION HEADER IS SENT!

Here is my code used for Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(.PATCH, path, parameters: ["email":"new@mail.com"],     encoding: .JSON, headers: ["Authorization":"token \    ((User.sharedUser().token)!)"]).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200{
                print("success")
            }else{
                print("Error")
            }
        }
```

and here is code with NSURLConnection:

```
let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
request.HTTPMethod = "PATCH"
request.addValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

do{
    let bodyData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["email":"nuv@gmail.com"], options: [])
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    {
        (response, data, error) in
        if let mdata = data {
            let contents = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(contents)
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        }
}catch{
    print("failed serialization")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC, the `Authorization` header is one of those headers that `NSURLSession` reserves for its own purposes, and may overwrite with its own values—particularly if you're sending something that looks like normal HTTP authentication.

Can you send an `X-Authorization` header instead?

Comment: thanks for response)Yes i can use any other header, but why is that undocumented? Why it starts to use authorization header only for PUT and PATCH requests? And it completely removes authorization header, not using it(sniffed traffic). Thanks )

Comment: It actually is documented.  Search for "Reserved HTTP Headers" at https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest?language=objc and you'll find it.

Comment: This is one of those things where you can sometimes get away with it, so it leads to a false sense of security.  And then when you send something that looks too much like basic auth or whatever, it suddenly gets stomped on.  It might be worth filing a bug to ask for a delegate method to let you control that header field more directly.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who is looking for Alamofire 5(AF 5) solution here's the solution:

```
let headers: [String:String] = [...]
let params: [String: Any] = [...]
let url = URL(...)
let redirector = Redirector(behavior: Redirector.Behavior.modify({ (task, urlRequest, resp) in
  var urlRequest = urlRequest
  headers.forEach { header in
    urlRequest.addValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.key)
  }
  return urlRequest
  }))
  //use desired request func of alamofire and your desired enconding
  AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                //handleDataResponse...
            }.redirect(using: redirector)
```

Comment: @John glad to hear that :)